# Determine the style of soft-keyboard being presented, tablet or phone style

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I'd like to programmatically determine if a device is presenting a tablet or phone style keyboard.  Although there are many different Android soft-keyboard implementations, there are for the most part two distinct key layouts.  One for phones and the other for tablets.  Thanks for your help!

Note: I'm referring to the orientation of character keys to one another.  On phone keyboards, the second two rows of characters are aligned, with the first row offset by 50%.  Tablet keyboard are have a much more arbitrary offset that mimics a physical keyboard layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concept of "tablet or phone style keyboard" does not reflect reality. There are input method editors that don't even have *keys*. The notion that "phone keyboards, the second two rows of characters are aligned, with the first row offset by 50%" may be true for some input method editors used on phones, but certainly not all, and it is certainly not a requirement.

So, you are certainly welcome to determine the screen size by any of the standard approaches (resource sets, `Configuration`, etc.). But you have no way to know:

- if the input method editor the user is presently using has keys
- if so, what the physical relationship is between those keys (e.g., "the second two rows of characters are aligned")

Comment: Ok, so there's no way to query the keyboard to determine any information about it?  The app I'm porting requires you to type text from memory.  On iOS it let's you hit any key adjacent to the correct key, which allows for very fast typing.  I'm familiar with the many different android soft-keyboard styles, but I only need to handle the two primary layouts since this is a nice-to-have feature.  It will still work if I guess wrong about the keyboard style.  I'm thinking I'll default to tablet layout for x-large screens if there's no better way to guess what keyboard layout is being used.

Comment: @bgolson: "so there's no way to query the keyboard to determine any information about it?" -- correct. "On iOS it let's you hit any key adjacent to the correct key, which allows for very fast typing" -- most Android input method editors will be QWERTY. "the two primary layouts" -- there is no such concept. There are thousands of Android devices, spanning 100+ input method editors, and that's just the ones that ship with the hardware, ignoring ones the user downloads. You are assuming that all devices look like the few that are in front of you, and that is not a safe assumption.

Comment: Thanks so much for your feedback.  For now, since I can't think of any alternatives I'm going to stick with the assumption about the two key layouts, but also provide user preferences so they can alter the set of adjacent keys associated with each key on the keyboard, or just turn the typing helper function off altogether.  I do believe 95+% of keyboards fall in to one of the two layouts I mentioned above (I'm referring to only the letter keys and their relationship to one another)